# while loop not working correctly with .readline python

Tags: python-3.x

Ill start off by saying im very much a beginner in coding and im working with an online course to learn. Unfortunately ive come up against an issue which i cant seem to find a work around.

im trying to read a line from a file and then assign it to a variable. im then asking for input from the user, and then (within a while loop) if that users input matches the variable to open up another file and follow the action.

here is my code currently:

```
user1 = open ("holiday.txt", "w")
user1.write ("Holiday Location: " + holiday_loc + "\n")
user1.write ("Total Price: £" + str(total_price) + "\n")
user1.write ("Total People: " + str(total_people) + "\n")
user1.close()
print ("Here are a list of commands")
commands = open ("commands.txt", "r")
# command_line 1 = show data
# command_line2 = price PP
command_line1 = commands.readline()
command_line2 = commands.readline()
print (command_line1 + command_line2)
commands.close()
cl1 = command_line1
cl2 = command_line2
answer = input ("What would you like to do? ")
while answer != "cl1" or answer != "cl2":
    print("Im sorry, there is no such command")
    answer = input("What would you like to do? ")
else:
    if answer == cl1:
        show_data = open ("holiday.txt", "r")
        line1 = show_data.readline()
        line2 = show_data.readline()
        line3 = show_data.readline()
        print (line1 + "\n" + line2 + "\n" + line3)
    elif answer == cl2:
        print (line2/line3)
```

clarification:

if the user input's "show data" or "price pp" (which has been assigned the variable (cl1 & cl2) it's suppose to skip the "no such command" part of the loop and go to the else part. But currently it doesn't, ATM whatever the user inputs even if it is the right command or anything else it just treats the statement as true and prints "no such command" line. And I don't understand why, would it have anything to do with assigning variables from .readline commands maybe ?